# How do I beat Ogre in Tekken 3 with some other player?

Tags: tekken-3

When my player falls to the ground, Ogre keeps on attacking with triple kicks.

If I try to stand up Ogre attacks with his hands, knocking me back over.

When I get close to Ogre, he grabs me in a grapple, and triple kicks me.

This takes off about 75% of my health.

**Addendum**: After thinking carefully I noticed that I loose most of my power when the Ogre counterattacks me after blocking any of my attack. He most of the time blocks my attacks and if I make some distance he runs toward me and attacks with 3 flying kicks, among which the last last two are unblockable and takes 30% of the health. Now after blocking any of his attack if I try to immediately counter attack it becomes slow and contrary Ogre hits first before my counter attack. So Ogre can counter attack me after blocking but I can't do the some.

How to I defeat him?

Comment: It will help a great deal if you tell us what character you are playing as. I found that some characters were a cakewalk, and some, absolute terror to defeat Ogre with. Some characters also had a "easy mode" that only applied to the particular way a move they could do worked.

That said, with persistence, a 10 year old can beat Ogre with any character (which in itself tells you how long it has been since I played the game)

Comment: @Timelord64 I play with King and Paul.

Comment: @Timelord64 The grapple he uses is one hand grapple and then he continues with triple kicks. Is there any character which is most effective against Ogre, e.g. someone which is quite fast.

Answer (score 3):

What you have to understand is that Tekken does rely on a level of skill, especially at the higher levels.

For Ogre to be able to grapple you and deal a whopping three-quarters of your total health in one attack, you must be playing on one of the harder levels of difficulty.

What you are likely lacking is reaction time. Do not feel offended or self-conscious, as Tekken is a game often played in Video Game tournaments, where the difference between zero and hero can literally fall down to a couple of milliseconds (thats 1/1000th of a second).

Lower the difficulty rating, and try again. When the boss becomes "beatable", try to replay the fight over and over, preferably with the same character (your fighter of choice).

Over time, you will become more reactive, and capable of handling the boss on higher levels of difficulty. Just increase the difficulty as it becomes easier for you.

If all else fails, you can [unlock Gon](http://eng.tekkenpedia.com/wiki/Gon) and use him. [Gon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gon_%28manga%29) is unique, in that he is a small character, and automatically avoids high-attacks and grapples.

He also has a few "dog" abilities that can easily be repeated over and over again to attack the opponent without giving them an opportunity to counter-attack.

Comment: Actually I am not playing against computer. I am playing with my friend. The problem doesn't seem to be reaction time. Most of the moves are difficult to make on keyboard. On the other hand my friend uses only three moves every time, 1 grapple, 2. One hand attack which if blocked pushes me back. 3. Triple kicks with the third kick being a surprise that may be high kick or usual lower lick. The problem is once my player falls the kicks are unavoidable. I always got two triple kicks simultaneously, which can't be blocked or counter attacked.The one hand attack of Ogre is also uncounterattackable

Comment: You will find Gon offers the same advantages towards human players, as it does AI players. I find other players look down on the use of Gon, but for the same reason they look down on the sort of player that only uses three particular moves. I would consider investing in a controller, if the keyboard is difficult. A cheap controller can cost about the same as a cheap gaming keyboard.

Comment: Gon doesn't work at all. At the very start of the game Ogre starts with triple kicks which have to be blocked. After the block I could only hit him some small attack which only takes 5% of his health. He again goes for triple kicks and the times he hit the third kick as the upper kick he takes almost 20% power.

Answer (score 2):

> **Sidesteps** are performed by tapping up or down. They can be used to avoid ordinary attacks, unblockable attacks and throws. –[tekken.wikia](http://tekken.wikia.com/wiki/Sidestepping)

You can also roll backwards or sideways to get up, or side step after rolling, as suggested at [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718273-tekken-revolution/66546722). But if your opponent has learned how to exploit back techs, as explained below, you're going to need some more practice to level the playing field.

> Getting Up From the Ground
>
> **Back tech**: This is done by holding B as you hit the ground. This causes you to roll backwards and end in a standing position. This is useful to avoid followup ground hits, or avoid the mixup an opponent might try if you were to tech to the side. The downside to this is that if you back tech too close, the opponent can dash in and either float combo you out of your back tech, or dash in and hit you with a mid move, as there are frames towards the end of the back tech that leave you ducking. Also, if you get knocked far away, a backroll tech may put you in range for the opponent to use an unblockable running shoulder tackle. –[tekkenzaibatsu.com](http://www.tekkenzaibatsu.com/forums/showthread.php?threadid=113442)

---

> I play with King and Paul. –the OP

Both characters who heavily rely on punches and grappling; two of the harder things to get the timing right and they're two of the slower guys. All this game is, is timing. And if you (like me) can't time it; button mash it:

I forgot his name so I googled `tekken 3 kicking guy` : [Hwoarang](https://www.google.com/search?q=tekken%203&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=tekken%203%20kicking%20guy)

I found it rather intuitive -when to start spamming *the other kick button*- once he spins around after kicking a few times. – If you two can punch each other, you're already standing too close.

That being said, I find King to be one of the most difficult characters to defeat if played well, however he is *the* easiest guy to beat if they don't know how to use him.

---

*How do I defeat someone playing Orge, while I'm using a keyboard?*

**Step one, get a controller.** Step two, select any character with a power kick. Time said kick to coincide with opponent's advance (I prefer Yoshimitsu's or Hwoarang's). Repeat until you both agree to pick different characters.

Comment: Sidesteps aren't avoiding any attacks rather I lost by 10-0. I will now try other things which you have mentioned.

Comment: Holding B while falling doesn't do nothing. And nor does button mashing do anything rather after he blocks my button-mashed-kick or punch he counter attacks me. On the other hand I can't counter attack him after blocking. Lastly what is power kick?

Comment: @user31782 `b` on a PlayStation controller is 'backwards'. [*"Double tap forward and 3 is a powerful roundhouse kick."*](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718273-tekken-revolution/68378093) (3 is left kick). Yoshimitsu's is a roundhouse, Hwoarang's is a forward jump kick. If you see blue smoke, that's it.

Comment: Matches begin at a distance where Hwoarang can kick you in the face. With Yoshimitsu, you have to advance or wait.

Comment: Holding backwards leads me to have Ogre's one hand attack. My opponent blocks Howrang's any kick including power kick and then counter kicks me which cause a lot of damage. Howrang's flying triple kicks are useful. Yoshumitsu's roundhouse kick also doesn't work because it is slow and before his leg could reach Ogre he attacks with his one hand.

Comment: I think that the major problem is the emulator because when I play against computer in practice mode at hard level-final round I can easily counter attack Ogre but when I play two player mode my keys don't work the same as they did in practice mode; its reason seem to be that my opponent keep pressing d+f which halts my keys momentarily.

Comment: @user31782 Well that dog just ain't gonna hunt. And this has become more of a SuperUser.SE question, IMO. Your tactics have nothing to do with it if your inputs aren't working. Unless you both have controllers this isn't really (fair) about how to beat someone playing a specific guy.

Comment: Yes, I've asked it there http://superuser.com/q/951188/375284 . I played with Paul against Ogre in practice(Hard)mode and when Ogre used tripple kicks I blocked them and 1. either kicked, 2. or if I am crouched then I used d/f,1+2 attack but when I play in two player mode if I try to do the same I got attacked by Ogre's kicks. I think I should play on actual PlayStation to see how things actually works.

Comment: @user31782 - Played on a real PS would be ideal, but a good enough CPU and two controllers might preform even better. Also, try the [ePSXe](http://www.emulator-zone.com/doc.php/psx/) emulator. I'd suggest buying at least one controller, to free up the keyboard, and you could switch off who's using it.

Comment: I have tried everything now. Controller, PS, diff characters - Gon, Eddy etc everything. Ogre has largest range and he takes highest power as compared to other characters in one shot. I conclude that Tekken 3 has some loop holes for Ogre. Anyone who figure out these loop holes and practice properly with Ogre is unbeatable..

Comment: @user31782 [Tekken 3 World Tournament Video, 1999](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-IOc7L2MvGE) No one that I can see *ever* used Ogre. From what I can tell, the final match was Nina vs. Paul. As everyone mentions everywhere, it all comes down to personal preference. The only thing you haven't tried is fighting against someone else, whose best *isn't* Ogre. 15 years ago I would have said the same thing about Eddy; my friend's favorite. There's no character that's a shoe-in and wins every tournament. Tekken 3 is an extremely well balanced game and it is considered the pinnacle of the series.

Comment: All charters have loop hoes. Anyone who figures out these loop holes and practices properly with *anyone*, is unbeatable. Especially if they've figured out *your* loop holes. Strangely enough, Ogre lacks the best loop hole: string combos: "Overall, [Ogre] only has three unique moves (Ancient Power, Serpent's Venom, and Azteca Shoot). Because Ogre "stole" most of their techniques, it is the **only character with no string-combo**, other than Gon" –[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogre_%28Tekken%29) IMO, a longer reach, hard hitting attacks and being sort of slow isn't worth it.

Comment: Ogre is the fastest character. String combo is waste. Ogre blocks it and then counter attacks. The problem is Ogre doesn't let you reach him. If I could reach him to the punching distance with Paul then I can fall him down with d+4,2 attack.

Comment: Do Tekken 3 international tournaments occur nowadays?

Comment: @user31782 I'd expect you to beat anyone who lets you within punching distance, as I expect to be defeated by anyone who can get within it. IMO, when you say, "How do I defeat him?" *him* is your friend who likes to play Ogre. *He* is the one you need to learn how to defeat. *He* has learned that all you are going to try to do is d+4,2. The last line of my answer is not a throw-away: learn some guys cheap trick and use it until your friend calls BS. Agree to choose diff guys, when he understands that him using Ogre is also a cheap trick. - I highly doubt that 15yo game still has int. tourneys.

Comment: @user31782 - Timelord64 had it right all along, "dog" him; that's what he's doing to you.

Comment: The power kick doesn't work. Actually Ogre never advance literally. When he is just before the touching range he uses "Front Strike f+2". The power kick either misses or gets blocked. Then Ogre again does f+2 which is automatically unblockable(loop hole). I can't block him, nor can I  attack him. I just have to try lucky shots that is his f+2 coincide with my kick -- which rarely happens. We even played with hard-level final-round practice mode to check is Ogre really the best character of Tekken-3. And Ogre easily beat anyone even in hard mode.

Comment: I thing 'Ogre', 'True Ogre' and 'Gon' are not allowed in competitive tournaments.